# Error Installing Snort - dnet header not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, snort

Snort Version: `2.9.11.1`

While compiling, getting following error on AWS EC2. Tried googling but the provided solutions not working.

```
./configure --enable-sourcefire && make && make install
```

> ERROR!  dnet header not found, go get it from
> http://code.google.com/p/libdnet/ or use the --with-dnet-*
> options, if you have it installed in an unusual place
> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop

Comment: Did you try `./configure --enable-sourcefire --with-dnet=no && make && make install` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
yum install libdnet-devel
```

Try to install this, this has worked for me in the past on Debian for the same error:

```
yum search libdnet
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1040 packages excluded due to repository priority protections

N/S matched: libdnet 
libdnet-devel.i686 : Header files for libdnet library
libdnet-devel.x86_64 : Header files for libdnet library
libdnet-progs.x86_64 : Sample applications to use with libdnet
libdnet.i686 : Simple portable interface to lowlevel networking routines
libdnet.x86_64 : Simple portable interface to lowlevel networking routines

Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Comment: check my edit, one of those odds are the libdnet-devel.x86_64 will be it.

Comment: Not working  Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Warning: No matches found for: libdnet
No matches found

Comment: Its AWS ec2 instance

Comment: What distro? Amazon Linux AMI? Ubuntu?

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09

Comment: what does this do? yum install libdnet-devel.x86_64 libdnet.x86_64

Comment: yum install libdnet-devel.x86_64 libdnet.x86_64
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
No package libdnet-devel.x86_64 available.
No package libdnet.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 0):

`apt install libdumbnet-dev` worked for me on Ubuntu

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/930212/1652162)